# SharePoint calculated column if then else statement issue

Tags: sharepoint, if-statement, calculated-columns

Trying to use a calculated column to convert a user ID [LOGBY] to an actual last name in SharePoint 2010.  Keep getting a syntax error.  I am under the 7 nested if statement limit.  Anyone have any thoughts"?

> `=IF([LOGBY]=”P2091″,”BARNES”,IF([LOGBY]=”2307″,”FIELDS”,IF([LOGBY]=”2398″,”BARTLETT”,IF([LOGBY]=”P2403″,”GREENE”,IF([LOGBY]=”P2415″,”FOSTER”,IF([LOGBY]=”P819″,”CALDER″,""))))))`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you're using Word to edit your code or something. Your quotes are totally wrong: `”` and `″` are not valid. use real `"` instead, e.g. use a proper code editor, not a word processor.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.  I am such a rookie!!

Comment: The lesson here is to always use a "text" editor IDE for writing code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You've messed up with some text editor, there is difference between

1. ″ ASCII -> 8243
2. ” ASCII -> 8221
3. " ASCII -> 34 **use that one!**

> =IF([LOGBY]="P2091","BARNES",IF([LOGBY]="2307","FIELDS",IF([LOGBY]="2398","BARTLETT",IF([LOGBY]="P2403","GREENE",IF([LOGBY]="P2415","FOSTER",IF([LOGBY]="P819","CALDER",""))))))